# How to configure role based access permissions in C# and ASP.NET using Identity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

What I have tried so far:

I placed a `Web.config` in a folder I want to protect with the following content which should grant access to `admin`, `second_level` and `third_level` users only.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="admin"/>
      <allow roles="second_level"/>
      <allow roles="third_level"/>
      <deny roles="first_level"/>
      <deny roles="blocked"/>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

In the main `Web.config` I put:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="myapp.App_Code.SecurityAppRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" createPersistentCookie="false" cookieProtection="All">
  <providers>
    <clear />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

The custom role provider:

```
 namespace myapp.App_Code
{
    public class SecurityAppRoleProvider : System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderBase
    {
        public SecurityAppRoleProvider()
        {
            var i = 0; // breakpoint here will never be reached?
        }

    }
}
```

At this point there are some things I am struggling with:

1. The `<deny users="*" />` works. The ASP.NET app redirects me to the login page which is the beahvior I need. But the roles are are not considered by web application. Which means all users are currently blocked to access the page even if they are member of role `admin`.
2. `SecurityAppRoleProvider` will never be instanced so I guess I need to register the custom role provider else where?
3. Is not there a default Role Provider which should be used in connection with ASP.Net Identity Framework without code a custom one?

Answer (score 0):

I put this into main `Web.config` to solve the issue.

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/your-app-name"/>
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/your-app-name"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```